Can't remove printer
I have a Brother HL-L2370DW that I added with the installation utility from brother.com, and it worked for several years, but now when I queue a print job, it stays stuck "processing".
When I remove HLL2370DW from Settings->Printers it is replaced with Brother_HL_L2370DW_series, and that stubbornly refuses to be removed.
lpstat does not show it:
$ sudo lpstat -p
printer Pro9500II-series is idle.  enabled since Sun 24 Mar 2024 01:47:01 PM CDT
printer Pro9500II-TurboPrint is idle.  enabled since Mon 22 Jan 2024 04:46:56 PM CST

lpadmin says it does not exist:
$ sudo lpadmin -x Brother_HL_L2370DW_series
lpadmin: The printer or class does not exist.

Yet it remains in Settings->printers.


Does this answer your question? How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?
